# posting a flurry of msgs to rsyslog causes process hangs in openlog()

Tags: c, rhel, rsyslog

We use the rsyslogd daemon for logging debug messages in several applications.  With full debug on, the server will hang in the openlog() call being made in the application to log messages.  Looks to be doing a lock in the kernel library code in glibc.

Is this a known issue under load or are we exposing some contention issue in the kernel?  RHEL 6.4 running kernel 2.6.32-358.2.1 (i386).

rsyslog version was 8.4.1 but we upgraded to latest this afternoon 8.17 and are still running tests to see if the problem continues.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is more properly asked on the StackExchange site [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). You may also want to try the red-hat mailing list. StackOverflow is a programming Question & Answer site.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I wouldn't say it is completely off-topic here, as it is clear that it is the `openlog` is being called from their app.

Comment: It's a borderline call, the question seems to ask for whether there is a known issue with `openlog` as it relates to RHEL 6.4 and doesn't really provide any code to evaluate. (at least that was my thought) Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I can see it both ways.  Post the code, the stack trace of the stuck process showing where it's stuck, and it stays here as it's then a coding question.  Without the code and stack trace, it's a configuration/"Is this a known bug?" question that should be moved.

Comment: upgrading to 8.17 of rsyslog and tweaking the rsyslog.conf to use more threads and larger arraysize seems to have done the trick.  no hangs today.

Comment: what I'm guessing was going on it the non-tuned setup of rsyslog was not able to keep up with many process hammering at the /dev/log device and this contention resulted in the hang.  since putting 8.17 of rsyslog on with tuning tips the rsyslog site, has not re-occurred.